# CSS in IE vs Chrome woes... Can anyone help me line these up on the right in Chrome? It works in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

To make this question least confusing, I made a JS Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hollycotta/27K5V/5/

If you view it in IE, the result is lined up on the right.

If you view it in Chrome, the squares are not lined up on the right side and look messy.

Does anyone know what missing piece will make it line up in Chrome and IE?

I need to keep the div IDs 'Tier3', 'Tier2', and 'Tier1' because I programmatically hide and show them depending on other parts of my form.  There is also a lot of javascript that uses the input IDs, etc.  Is there a way to make a CSS change only to fix this?

Thank you so much in advance for help, this has left me stumped.

-Holly

Since I need to provide code as well when I link a JS Fiddle, I will paste the CSS here but it is all in the JS Fiddle with the html markup that creates my problem:

```
      #leftRadioButtonOptions {
position: relative;
left : 5px;
top  : 65px;
width: 230px;
text-align:right;
      }

      input[type=radio] {
         display:none;
   }

      input[type=radio] + label{
         display:inline-block;
         margin:-2px;
         padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         font-size: 10px;
         line-height: 12px;
         color: transparent;
         text-align: center;
         text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
         vertical-align: middle;
         cursor: pointer;
         background-color: #f5f5f5; 
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
         background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
         background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
         background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
         background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
         background-repeat: repeat-x;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
         border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
         border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
   }

   input[type=radio]:checked + label{
            background-image: none;
         outline: 0;
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         background-color:white;
    color:black;

   }
```

Comment: i'll have a look, but in the future, use ff/chrome as your base browser, it's easier to fix things that way around

Comment: @Robert, well my original requirements said "Only support IE 8, 9, and 10."  I made it public a few months ago, and now they want me to support Chrome, so I am going back in and trying to fix it.

For personal projects, I always use firefox.  :)  So I agree with you, it just didn't go this way with this non-personal project.  Thanks SO much for having a look!

Comment: hmmm ..looks the same to me in ff 25/ chrome 31 / ie 11

Comment: hehe, they notice that chrome has 2-3 times the user base of IE ? :-)

Comment: @Robert Most of the users I support have a specific laptop with an image that had IE 8, 9, or 10.   If you try that fiddle in IE 9 or 10 for example it lines up.   If you look below, adding the nbsp in where he did fixed it in Chrome but then messed it back up the exact same way in IE 9/10.  I can't find something that makes it line up in both IE 9/10 and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like thing about blank text nodes.

Not a good way to fix it, but adding `&nbsp;` at the end of each block fixed aligning issue in Chrome.

Actually it's better not to use `<br>`s, but wrap every line you need into `div`.

Comment: if that works, I will use it!  What did you mean by at the end of each block?  I tried after each line and that didn't work, did you mean at the end of each </div>?  Whatever you got to work in Chrome, I'll take it!

I tried it at the end of each Tier's </div> and that didn't work either.  If you could fork a JS FIddle to show me what worked, I'd be eternally grateful!  @kirilloid

Comment: I see it lined it up in Chrome, but with that change, it is now out of alignment in IE.  Try your fiddle in IE. :(

Comment: That actually does work, it just really messed up all surrounding CSS for the rest of my form.  I hate CSS so much at times like this!  Thank you though, you did make it work for my portion that I put in the Fiddle so I'm marking you as my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

How this ?

I wrapped each item in a div and added this to your original css

```
.entry {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0 ;    
}
```

And the html

```
<div id="leftRadioButtonOptions">
    <div id="Tier3">
        <div class="entry">
            Overall Status:
            <input id="overallGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="overallGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="overallYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="overallYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="overallRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="overallRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>

        <div class="entry">
            Schedule:
            <input id="scheduleGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="scheduleGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="scheduleYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="scheduleYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="scheduleRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="scheduleRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>

        <div class="entry">
            Risks/Issues/Concern:
            <input id="risksGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="risksGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="risksYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="risksYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="risksRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="risksRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>

        <div class="entry">
            Customer Satisfaction:
            <input id="satisfactionGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="satisfactionGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="satisfactionYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="satisfactionYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="satisfactionRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="satisfactionRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Tier2">
        <div class="entry">
            Budget:
            <input id="budgetGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="budgetGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="budgetYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="budgetYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="budgetRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="budgetRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>

        <div class="entry">
            Deliverables:
            <input id="deliverablesGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="deliverablesGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="deliverablesYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="deliverablesYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="deliverablesRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="deliverablesRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Tier1">
        <div class="entry">
            Scope/Contract:
            <input id="scopeGreen" type="radio" />
            <label for="scopeGreen" style="background-color: #03ce07;"><b>G </b></label>
            <input id="scopeYellow" type="radio" />
            <label for="scopeYellow" style="background-color: #fff31a;"><b>Y </b></label>
            <input id="scopeRed" type="radio" />
            <label for="scopeRed" style="background-color: red;"><b>R </b></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27K5V/6/

Comment: Thanks, this would work too!  I went with kirilloid's which was a similar concept.  I appreciate your guys' help so much!

Comment: No problem. He answered first and i think we have the same solution !